# How to add and use all the different JDK versions in netbean?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using windows 7 64, IDE netbeans 8. I have got some projects compiled in different jdk versions jdk 6, jdk 7 and jdk 8,   manytimes I face the error of major.minor, to avoid it I am changing the jdk according to need, but it consumes a lot of time to install and uninstall jdks again and again. Is there any easy way to add and use all the jdks in the netbeans by switching etc.?

Comment: At least on linux, there's no problem in installing diferent JDK versions at the same time. Netbeans has a setting to choose the JDK. So un-/reinstalling should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a project open, you can go to file -> project properties. At the bottom of the window you'll find a menu labeled source/binary format. You should be able to select the jdk version there.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am seeing there jdk from 1.2 to 8, does it mean that all are available? and I have simply to select, is it so? Sorry for this silly question being new to java, kindly confirm it.

Comment: yep. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using ant/maven/gradle to build your project with, but you can specify the source and target compatibility for each specific project.

- maven -> http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html
- ant -> http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html
- gradle -> http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1223E

Answer (score 1):

See [FaqJdkHome](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome) and [How to set and use different JDK versions in NetBeans](https://blogs.oracle.com/charliebrown/entry/how_to_set_and_use).